# If $H$ is a subgroup of group $G$, and $aHa^{-1}=a^{-1}Ha$ for all $a \in G$, is $H$ a normal subgroup in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $H$ is a subgroup of group $G$, and $aHa^{-1}=a^{-1}Ha$ for all $a \in G$, is $H$ a normal subgroup in $G$?

I can only prove that $a^{2}Ha^{-2} \subseteq H$, is it not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be the dihedral group of order eight generated by $(13)$ and $(1234)$. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $(13)$, which is conjugate to the subbroup generated by $(24)$ in $G$ and so is not normal. However $H$ is fixed by all squares.